# How to call model method in other model file in magento2?

Tags: magento2, php

I want to call model method in other model file. i have created file (mobiledetect.php) in my "model folder" and i want to call this in service.php in in my custom function in same model folder.

please find my code here where i want call another model method. anyone have an idea for that please?

```
<?php

namespace Mymodule\Custom\Model;

use Mymodule\Custom\Api\ServiceInterface;


class Service implements ServiceInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Checkout\Helper\Data
     */
    private $checkoutHelper;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface
 */
private $storeManager;

/**
 * Constructor
 * @param \Magento\Checkout\Helper\Data $checkoutHelper
 * @param \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface $defaultConfigProvider
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Checkout\Helper\Data $checkoutHelper,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
) {

    $this->checkoutHelper = $checkoutHelper;
    $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
}

/**
 * Return URL
 * @return string
 */
public function redirect_url()
{

    //want to call model here of  mobiledetect.php
if(isMobile)

{

    //Return statement modified by Ravikant Varma

    return $this->checkoutHelper->getCheckout()->getCustomRedirectUrl();
}
else {

    return $this->storeManager->getStore()->getUrl('checkout/onepage/success/');


 }

}

}
```

Comment: add the another model mobiledetect.php into your question. you need to inject that class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To call the other model define the dependency in the constructor. Also define:  private $path;

```
public function __construct(
\Magento\Checkout\Helper\Data $checkoutHelper,
\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
\Your\Mobile\Detect\File\Path $path
) {
    $this->path = $path;
$this->checkoutHelper = $checkoutHelper;
$this->storeManager = $storeManager;
 }
```

I have given example in above code that's how you can define it in constructor and call it and call any function in other model using **$this->path->getFunctionName();**  That way you can do this.

You can replace that details with your details to see it working.